# PDFs generated with Dompdf library filling up tempfolder

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I am currently generating some pdfs with the dompdf library but every time a pdf is being generated my temp folder is being filled with this file and the images associated with it. I am trying to unlink or delete the pdf and any temp files generated with it but the following code is not giving the desired result. Does anyone know what else I can do in this situation?
I am using PHP and have installed the library with composer.

pdf code:

```
    // reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
//$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');
$dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
$dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);
$dompdf -> loadHtml($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
unlink($dompdf);
```

Comment: You can not `unlink` a variable reference. You would need to unlink the files created. Which files are not being removed?

Comment: @BrianS it seems when a pdf is generated a copy is made an stored in the temp files so I was trying to see if I could unlink or delete the file or since they all have the prefix "dompdf" targeting files with this prefix

Comment: I believe dompdf should be cleaning up after itself. You could try `unset($dompdf)` to see if that helps with clean up. I have seen instances where temp files were blanked out but not actually deleted. Never had time to investigate the cause. To delete the files manually you would use `unlink('/path/to/file');`.